# Distance reading with Garmin lidar lite v4 over I²C with Arduino Due fails when connecting stepper driver

Tags: arduino, i2c, lidar

I am using following configuration:

- Arduino Due
- [Garmin Lidar-lite V4](https://static.garmin.com/pumac/LIDAR-Lite%20LED%20v4%20Instructions_EN-US.pdf) distance reading by the Arduino over I²C
- Several Stepper motor controlled by the same Arduino through drivers ([DM320T](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/download/DM320T.pdf) and [DM542T](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/download/DM542T.pdf))

Here is the problem:
When the stepper drivers are disconnected (i.e. not powered), the distance readings work as expected over I2C, but as soon as I power the drivers, I can no longer perform distance measurements and it looks like the Lidar freezes.

It seems like there are interferences, but how to be sure? Where to start to solve this problem? Any suggestion on the steps to undertake?

The Arduino and the stepper drivers have separate power supplies, but grounds are put common.

Comment: Few things are needed. Like schematics and PCB and if multiple PCBs then wiring between them.

Comment: Common grounds and unwanted ground currents in circuit A leached from circuit B are a major concern.

Comment: Put an o-scope on the IIC lines to the Lidar and see what they are doing.